# Encoded HTML entities in mod message popup

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, top-bar, html-entities

New meta post alerts for mods are sometimes shown with HTML entities:

[image: apache 2.4 won't reload]

I think this is new, but possibly I've just been blind for several years, or maybe it only happens in rare conditions since some of the other instances seem fine. Possibly only happens in generated titles and code blocks?

Comment: I *think* the rare case here being that the entity is in a link (that was also converted by the site to show the title, rather than the URL).

Comment: @FEichinger That's what I meant by "generated titles", although the second example isn't that, it's a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when this has been fixed, but it seems to be no longer a problem anymore:

[image]

([here](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/60bc7f86ad6a7389e701251ff0316b0a) is the Markdown for that question)